# HTML elements won't align properly on mobile

Tags: html, css

The html elements on this simple to do list app i'm making won't properly align themselves when ran on mobile. Essentially when on mobile, the h1 tag should be in the center of the screen as well as the input box and add button under it and the tasks being added to the page, instead on mobile everything is off alignment. Any fixes?

```js
let task;
let text;
let addTask;
let list;
let taskNo = 0;
let remove;
let input = document.getElementById('message');
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');

input.addEventListener("keypress", function() {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        if (input.value === "") {
            alert("Please enter a task!");
        } else {
            createTask();
        }
    }
});

btn.onclick = function() {
    if (input.value === "") {
        alert("Please enter a task!");
    } else {
        createTask();
    }
};

function createTask() {
    
    task = input.value;
    
    addTask = document.createElement('li');
   
    text = document.createTextNode(task);
    
    addTask.appendChild(text);
    
    addTask.classList.add("task");
    
    taskNo++;
    
    addTask.id = taskNo;
    
    document.getElementById("taskList").appendChild(addTask);
    
    input.value = "";
    
    let list = document.getElementsByClassName("task");
    
    [...list].forEach(b => {
        b.addEventListener("click", () => {
            remove = document.getElementById(b.id);
            remove.parentNode.removeChild(remove);
        });
    });
}
```

```css
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #29313d;
    color: white;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 44px;
}

#input{
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#message, #btn{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

#message{
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    border: 4px solid coral;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 75%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#btn{
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: coral;
    border: 4px solid coral;
    color: black;
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 20%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#btn:focus{
    outline: none;
}

#message:focus{
    outline: none;
}

#input{
    height: 50px;
    width: 400px;
}

#taskList{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.task {
    margin: auto;
    width: 85%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 4px solid coral;
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

@media(max-width: 600px) {
    
    #container {
        width: 80%;
    }
    
    h1{
        margin: auto;
    }
    
    #message{
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    #btn{
        display: none;
    }
    
    
    .task{
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=10">
        <link href="resources/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="resources/logo.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png">
        <title>Jennis App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <h1>To Do List</h1>
            <div id="input">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="Please enter a new task">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Add">
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul id="taskList">
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script src="resources/code.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to make some css changes in `media`.

- Center the `container` for small device using `margin`
- Remove `display: none` for `#btn` in `media query`
- Use `flex` to align `add` button for small device
- `clearfix` the `.input-group` using `before` and `after`

```js
let task;
let text;
let addTask;
let list;
let taskNo = 0;
let remove;
let input = document.getElementById('message');
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');

input.addEventListener("keypress", function() {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        if (input.value === "") {
            alert("Please enter a task!");
        } else {
            createTask();
        }
    }
});

btn.onclick = function() {
    if (input.value === "") {
        alert("Please enter a task!");
    } else {
        createTask();
    }
};

function createTask() {
    
    task = input.value;
    
    addTask = document.createElement('li');
   
    text = document.createTextNode(task);
    
    addTask.appendChild(text);
    
    addTask.classList.add("task");
    
    taskNo++;
    
    addTask.id = taskNo;
    
    document.getElementById("taskList").appendChild(addTask);
    
    input.value = "";
    
    let list = document.getElementsByClassName("task");
    
    [...list].forEach(b => {
        b.addEventListener("click", () => {
            remove = document.getElementById(b.id);
            remove.parentNode.removeChild(remove);
        });
    });
}
```

```css
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #29313d;
    color: white;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 44px;
}

#input{
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#message, #btn{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

#message{
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    border: 4px solid coral;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 75%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#btn{
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: coral;
    border: 4px solid coral;
    color: black;
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 20%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#btn:focus{
    outline: none;
}

#message:focus{
    outline: none;
}

#input{
    height: 50px;
    width: 400px;
}

#taskList{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.task {
    margin: auto;
    width: 85%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 4px solid coral;
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

@media(max-width: 600px) {
    
    #container {
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto; /* to align center */
    }
    
    h1{
        margin: auto;
    }
    
    #message{
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    #btn{
        /* display: none; */
    }
    
    
    .task{
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    
    /***  Additional css ***/
    .input-group.flex {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .input-group:before, .input-group:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=10">
        <link href="resources/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="resources/logo.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png">
        <title>Jennis App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <h1>To Do List</h1>
            <div id="input">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="Please enter a new task">
                </div>
                <!-- Added one additional class -->
                <div class="input-group flex">
                    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Add">
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul id="taskList">
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script src="resources/code.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vy06jhu3/)